# simple code kivy login page shows black screen

Tags: kivy

i was doing a graphiclly user interface with kivy. i did exactly the same as the tutiorl. but the page shows black. here is my code, very simple. can someone tell me where i was wrong. thanks.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

Builder.load_file('design.kv')

class LoginScreen(Screen):
    pass

class RootWidget(ScreenManager):
    pass

class MainApp(App):
    def bulid(self):
        return RootWidget()

if __name__=="__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

```
<LoginScreen>:
    GridLayout:
        cols:1
        Gridlayout:
            cols:1
            Lable:
                text:"User Login"
            TextInput:
                hint_text:"Username"
            TextInput:
                hint_text:"Password"
            Button:
                text:"Login"
        Gridlayout:
            cols:2
            Button:
                text:"Forgot Password?"
            Button:
                text:"Sign Up"

<RootWidget>:
    LoginScreen:
```

Comment: Do you see any error messages?

Answer (score 0):

Spelling error.

```
def bulid(self):
```

should be:

```
def build(self):
```

Comment: Thank you so much. i really appreciate that. thank you